# Find the minimum value of $a_1^2+...+a_{n-1}^2$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $n \ge 2$ be an even integer. We consider all polynomials of the form
$x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +...+ a_1x + 1$, with real coefficients and having at least
one real zero. Determine the least possible value of $a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_{n-1}^2$.

This problem is from the book *Problems from the book* the Cauchy-Shwartz section. This is my approach,

We know that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k^2\ge 0^2+...+0^2+a_{n/2}^2+0^2+...+0^2=a_{n/2}^2$$
Which corresponds to the polynomial $x^n+a_{n/2}\cdot x_{n/2}^{n/2}+1$ Now this has a real root iff $|a_{n/2}|\ge 2$. Hence the minimum is $4$
So Am I done?

Comment: The book doesn't provide solutions @Arthur

Comment: Consider how  $x^6-x^4-x^2+1=0$ has real zeros at $x=\pm1$ even though $a_3=0$

Comment: Right, I'm mixing up with "Proofs from The Book". Sorry.

Comment: @PNT Your attempt states that $\sum a_k^2 \ge a^2_{n/2}$, which is indeed true, and then tried to find a lower bound for $|a_{n/2}|$.  I gave an example where  $a_{n/2}=0$ and incidentally also has  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k^2 =2$ rather than your suggested $4$

Comment: @Henry so is that the lower bound?

Comment: @PNT I have no idea.

Comment: @PNT Consider $x^n -\frac2{n-1}x^{n-1}-\frac2{n-1}x^{n-2}-\cdots - \frac2{n-1}x^{2}-\frac2{n-1}x+1 =0$.  This has a zero at $x=+1$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k^2 =\frac{4}{n-1}$ which decreases towards $0$ as $n$ increases.

Comment: $4/(n-1)$ is the minimum for fixed $n$, solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1545692p9374475